# PHP Warning - Unable to initialize module

Tags: php, module, warnings

My webpage is running really slow and I wanted to check error log and it is full with this error -

```
[11-Dec-2012 09:52:54 Europe/Helsinki] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: rar: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0
```

What is it? Can anyone know how to fix it? My site is running Joomla.

Comment: Looks like you haven't upgraded PHP modules, they are not compatible. Check extension_dir directive in php.ini

Answer (score 7):

This indicates that you updated your PHP version, but not the extension. Download the extensions from http://php.net/downloads.php

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is it possible to know which extension it its? @Osiris

Comment: @iKaspars Just run `php --version` at CLI and you'll get a list of all modules having this issue. Greetings.